"Why does grid-template-rows: n fr affect both the parent and child DOM elements at the same time?"


* {}
        
.ShellBox {
    display:flex;
}

.Shell {
    background-color: #0f0;
    width: 100px;
    display: grid;
}

.Shell1 {
    grid-template-rows: 0.1fr;
}

.Shell2 {
    grid-template-rows: 0.5fr;
}

.Shell3 {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.Box {
    min-height: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    border-top: 0 !important;
}

.Box>div {
    height: 99px;
    width: 98px;
}
<div class="ShellBox">
    <div>
        <div class="Shell Shell1">
            <div class="Box">
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="Shell Shell2">
            <div class="Box">
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="Shell Shell3">
            <div class="Box">
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="ShellBox">
    <div class="Shell Shell1">
        <div class="Box">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Shell Shell2">
        <div class="Box">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Shell Shell3">
        <div class="Box">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



The above describes the situation I encountered, and the following describes what I expected. What I don't understand is why this phenomenon occurs.
grid-template-rows: n fr affected both the parent's and the child's height at the same time. Why wasn't .Shell expanded, but instead, it became the expected height of grid-template-rows: n fr? Then .Box was affected by grid-template-rows: n fr again, resulting in grid-template-rows: n*n fr. I find this phenomenon quite interesting.
=============================

The result in Firefox matches what I expected. I encountered this issue in Google Chrome. Initially, I thought it was a CSS feature, but if it's caused by browser differences, I'm not sure whether this issue needs to be fixed.

Your question is not clear. Please edit your post to make it clearer what you are asking. Make sure you clearly explain your desired result and your chosen solution, and clarify the difference between your desired result and the actual results we are seeing in the snippet. Ideally you would add some sketches or mockups ... a picture is worth a thousand words.

@BrettDonald Please click "Run code snippet", and you'll notice that the border doesn't align with expectations. Modifying grid-template-rows will show that the height of .Box seems to be influenced by fr twice.

What do you want the actual heights of .Shell and of .Box to be?

Regarding the requirements, I have already resolved them. What I don't understand now is why .Box is affected by fr twice and why .Shell is affected by fr. I originally thought that 0.5fr would make .Shell expand to 100px and .Box to 50px, but now it turns out that .Shell is 50px and .Box is 25px. When set to 0.1fr, .Shell is 10px and .Box is 1px. @AHaworth

note that Firefox is giving a different output

Wow, that's true! So, is this caused by differences in the browser?@TemaniAfif

I don't know if you're confusing fr for percentages, but from the spec:

<flex> values between 0fr and 1fr have a somewhat special behavior: when the sum of the flex factors is less than 1, they will take up less than 100% of the leftover space.
A track’s <flex> value is effectively a request for some proportion of the leftover space, with 1fr meaning “100% of the leftover space”; then if the tracks in that axis are requesting more than 100% in total, the requests are rebalanced to keep the same ratio but use up exactly 100% of it. However, if the tracks request less than the full amount (such as three tracks that are each .25fr) then they’ll each get exactly what they request (25% of the leftover space to each, with the final 25% left unfilled).

By default, your grid div is 0px high. Its contents then push it to 100px height. And then you request 50% of that. So that's what you get.

1fr .Box => height = 100px
0.5fr .Box => height ≈ 25px
0.1fr .Box => height ≈ 1px
This is not the result I wanted @Siguza

If you modify the .Shell's grid-template-rows property, you'll find that the border position of .Box does not meet expectations. @Siguza

What are your expectations? The border is exactly where .Box ends, idk what else you would expect, or why.

Why are both .Shell and .Box affected by 0.5fr at the same time? I want .Box to be 50px, but it becomes 25px instead.
